# Pass python function as callback to C library

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I have C DLL library and I try add python interface to it. Here is header file:

```c
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int keyIdx         : 8;        // index of the G key or mouse button, for example, 6 for G6 or Button 6
    unsigned int keyDown        : 1;        // key up or down, 1 is down, 0 is up
    unsigned int mState         : 2;        // mState (1, 2 or 3 for M1, M2 and M3)
    unsigned int mouse          : 1;        // indicate if the Event comes from a mouse, 1 is yes, 0 is no.
    unsigned int reserved1      : 4;        // reserved1
    unsigned int reserved2      : 16;       // reserved2
} GkeyCode;

// Callback used to allow client to react to the Gkey events. It is called in the context of another thread.
typedef void (__cdecl *logiGkeyCB)(GkeyCode gkeyCode, const wchar_t* gkeyOrButtonString, void* context);

typedef struct
{
    logiGkeyCB gkeyCallBack;
    void* gkeyContext;
} logiGkeyCBContext;

// Enable the Gkey SDK by calling this function
BOOL LogiGkeyInit(logiGkeyCBContext* gkeyCBContext);

// Enable the Gkey SDK by calling this function if not using callback. Use this initialization if using Unreal Engine
BOOL LogiGkeyInitWithoutCallback();

//Enable the Gkey SDK be calling this function if not using context. Use this initialization if working with Unity Engine
BOOL LogiGkeyInitWithoutContext(logiGkeyCB gkeyCallBack);

// Check if a mouse button is currently pressed
BOOL LogiGkeyIsMouseButtonPressed(const int buttonNumber);

// Get friendly name for mouse button
wchar_t* LogiGkeyGetMouseButtonString(const int buttonNumber);

// Check if a keyboard G-key is currently pressed
BOOL LogiGkeyIsKeyboardGkeyPressed(const int gkeyNumber,const  int modeNumber);

// Get friendly name for G-key
wchar_t* LogiGkeyGetKeyboardGkeyString(const int gkeyNumber,const  int modeNumber);

// Disable the Gkey SDK, free up all the resources.
void LogiGkeyShutdown();
```

I try something like this:

```py
import ctypes
import time

# Define the GkeyCode structure
class GkeyCode(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("keyIdx", ctypes.c_uint, 8),
        ("keyDown", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ("mState", ctypes.c_uint, 2),
        ("mouse", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ("reserved1", ctypes.c_uint, 4),
        ("reserved2", ctypes.c_uint, 16)
    ]

# Define the logiGkeyCBContext structure
class logiGkeyCBContext(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("gkeyCallBack", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, GkeyCode, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_void_p)),
        ("gkeyContext", ctypes.c_void_p)
    ]

# Load the Logitech Gaming G-key SDK dynamic library
dll_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Logitech Gaming Software\\GkeySDK_8.57.148\\Lib\\GameEnginesWrapper\\x64\\LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper.dll"
gkey_lib = ctypes.CDLL(dll_path)

# Define the callback function
def gkey_callback(gkeyCode, gkeyOrButtonString, context):
    print(f"Received G-key or button event: keyIdx={gkeyCode.keyIdx}, keyDown={gkeyCode.keyDown}, mState={gkeyCode.mState}, mouse={gkeyCode.mouse}")
    print(f"G-key or button string: {gkeyOrButtonString}")
    print(f"Context: {context}")

# Create an instance of the logiGkeyCBContext structure
context = logiGkeyCBContext()
callback_func_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, GkeyCode, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_void_p)
callback_func = callback_func_type(gkey_callback)
context.gkeyCallBack = callback_func
context.gkeyContext = ctypes.c_void_p(0)  # Set the context to whatever is appropriate

# Call the Logitech Gaming G-key SDK function that accepts the logiGkeyCBContext structure
gkey_lib.LogiGkeyInit.restype = ctypes.c_bool
gkey_lib.LogiGkeyInit.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(logiGkeyCBContext),)

success = gkey_lib.LogiGkeyInit(ctypes.byref(context))
if success:
    print("Logitech Gaming G-key SDK initialized successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to initialize Logitech Gaming G-key SDK.")

c = 0
while c < 100:
    c += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)

# When done, shutdown the G-key SDK
gkey_lib.LogiGkeyShutdown()
```

Run, got success with initialization but then I try hit any G-key but callback is never executed?
Above is my code. `LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper.dll` library is part of Logitech G-Key SDK, for reference available here: https://www.logitechg.com/sdk/GkeySDK_8.57.148.zip

As Mark Tolonen requested I got working C code first with pooling and second with callback.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <LogitechGkeyLib.h>

int main() {
    LogiGkeyInit(NULL);
    printf("Press G-keys. Press Ctrl+C to exit.\n");
    while (true) {
        for (int index = 1; index <= LOGITECH_MAX_GKEYS; index++) {
            for (int mKeyIndex = 1; mKeyIndex <= LOGITECH_MAX_M_STATES; mKeyIndex++) {
                if (LogiGkeyIsKeyboardGkeyPressed(index, mKeyIndex))
                    wprintf(L"Button: %s", LogiGkeyGetKeyboardGkeyString(index, mKeyIndex));
            }
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
    LogiGkeyShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <LogitechGkeyLib.h>
#include <iostream>

void __cdecl GkeySDKCallback(GkeyCode gkeyCode, wchar_t* gkeyOrButtonString, void* /*pContext*/)
{
    std::wcout << L"G-Key pressed: " << gkeyOrButtonString << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    logiGkeyCBContext gkeyContext;
    ZeroMemory(&gkeyContext, sizeof(gkeyContext));
    gkeyContext.gkeyCallBack = (logiGkeyCB)GkeySDKCallback;
    gkeyContext.gkeyContext = NULL;

    LogiGkeyInit(&gkeyContext);

    std::cout << "Press G-keys. Press Ctrl+C to exit." << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {
        // Keep the program running to receive G-key events
    }
    LogiGkeyShutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

I try write some python code with `ctypes` or `cffi` to call C function from python but with out success.

Any body have idea what is wrong, or push me in right direction?

Comment: External links cannot be required in order to answer your question, so if there's any necessary info in that link, it must also be in your post itself, FYI. See [ask].

Comment: Can you get the library to work in minimal C code? If so, show that code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm not that good in C/C++, but I add example in C++ it is available in SDK itself (link is in question)

Comment: Take from that *C++* example only the code required to mimic what you've already written in *Python*. Unrelated hint: don't declare `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(...` twice. I think you might need a *GUI* in order for things to work.